# Pyspark how to join common columns values to a list value

Tags: sql, python-3.x, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

i am trying to join columns values to a list of values

```
df1=
name | department| state | id|
-----+-----------+-------+---+
James|Sales      |NY     |101
Maria|Finance    |CA     |102
Jen  |Marketing  |NY     |103



df2=
name | department| state | id|
-----+-----------+-------+---+
James|  Sales1   |null   |101
Maria|  Finance  |       |102
Jen  |           |NY2    |103

id_matchd_df=df1.join(df2,df1.id==df2.id,"inner")
id_matchd_df.show()
#result
+--------+----------+-----+----+-----+-----------+-------+---+
|name    |department|state|id  |name | department| state | id|
+--------+----------+-----+----+-----+-----------+-------+---+
|James   |Sales     |NY   |101 |James|  Sales1   |null   |101|  
|Maria   |Finance   |CA   |102 |Maria|  Finance  |       |102|
|Jen     |Marketing |NY   |103 |Jen  |           |NY2    |103|
```

But i need to join values of same columns with comma separated as look like below

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|name            | department          | state      | id         | 
['James','James']|['Sales','Sales']    |['NY',null] |['101','101']
['Maria','Maria']|['Finance','Finance']|['CA','']   |['102','102']
['Jen','Jen']    |['Marketing','']     |['NY','NY2']|['102','103']
```

Is there any solution to this ?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like a `union` instead of `join` to me?

Comment: Union the two data frames together.  Then you should be able to derive your first column.  In sql I'd do something like `case when row_number() over ... = 1 then id else null end`.

Comment: @Andrew i just have updated the questions.. the columns schema may vary from both data frame, so in such cases i am not sure union will work or not.. so now

Comment: That is a completely different question.

Comment: Yes.. actually i need to get difference of same id and that again have to populated in same respective columns... and this looks sufficient for my requirement..

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

# column to join on. This could become something like:
# join_col = df1.columns[0]
join_col = 'id'

joinDF = df1.join(df2, join_col, "inner")

cols = joinDF.columns
array_cols = set()

for col in cols:
    # store a reference to the new, temporary, `_array` column which we will create
    array_cols.add(f"{col}_array")
    # append the new `_array` column 
    #   using the `F.array` spark function to join the values together
    joinDF = joinDF.withColumn(col + '_array', F.array(df1[col], df2[col]))
    
# select only the joined (by `F.array`) columns and rename them back to the originals
joinDF \
    .select([F.col(ac).alias(ac.replace("_array","")) for ac in array_cols])
```

## Full solution

**Edit**: to answer the follow up detail:

> ..i may need to iterate through columns list that we collect from different data set

and

> [the] name of columns are unpredictable

`union` and `join` have been discussed in the comments...

Your original idea of `join`ing is the right one as `union` would result in 6 rows as per your example, whereas you want to maintain 3 rows as part the original dataframes.

Starting with your data:

```py
from pyspark.sql import Row, SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df1 = spark.createDataFrame([
    Row(name='James', department='Sales', state='NY', id=101),
    Row(name='Maria', department='Finance', state='CA', id=102),
    Row(name='Jen', department='Marketing', state='NY', id=103),
])

df2 = spark.createDataFrame([
    Row(name='James', department='Sales1', state='null', id=101),
    Row(name='Maria', department='Finance', state='', id=102),
    Row(name='Jen', department='', state='NY2', id=103),
])

df1.show()
df2.show()
```

gives:

```
+-----+----------+-----+---+
| name|department|state| id|
+-----+----------+-----+---+
|James|     Sales|   NY|101|
|Maria|   Finance|   CA|102|
|  Jen| Marketing|   NY|103|
+-----+----------+-----+---+

+-----+----------+-----+---+
| name|department|state| id|
+-----+----------+-----+---+
|James|    Sales1| null|101|
|Maria|   Finance|     |102|
|  Jen|          |  NY2|103|
+-----+----------+-----+---+
```

We can then `join` the dataframes and use the `array` function to combine the values of the columns, for a given row, into a single column for each.

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

# column to join on. This could become something like:
# join_col = df1.columns[0]
join_col = 'id'

joinDF = df1.join(df2, join_col, "inner")

cols = joinDF.columns
array_cols = set()

for col in cols:
    # store a reference to the new, temporary, `_array` column which we will create
    array_cols.add(f"{col}_array")
    # append the new `_array` column 
    #   using the `F.array` spark function to join the values together
    joinDF = joinDF.withColumn(col + '_array', F.array(df1[col], df2[col]))
    
# select only the joined (by `F.array`) columns and rename them back to the originals
joinDF \
    .select([F.col(ac).alias(ac.replace("_array","")) for ac in array_cols]) \
    .show()
```

gives:

```
+------------------+----------+--------------+----------+
|        department|     state|          name|        id|
+------------------+----------+--------------+----------+
|   [Sales, Sales1]|[NY, null]|[James, James]|[101, 101]|
|[Finance, Finance]|    [CA, ]|[Maria, Maria]|[102, 102]|
|     [Marketing, ]| [NY, NY2]|    [Jen, Jen]|[103, 103]|
+------------------+----------+--------------+----------+
```

Comment: thanks @tjheslin.. this looks good.. however, is there any way to dynamically create column. because i may need to iterate through columns list that we collect from different data set

Comment: Will it always be a case of two dataframes, with the same columns? If so then this should be manageable and I can update my answer.

Comment: we receive data frame from different data product and ideally columns of two data set  will  have same columns but  name of columns are unpredictable, hence cannot be hardcoded

Comment: @Adhi cloud I've updated my answer

Comment: ,.. i am getting below error from above execution "AnalaysisException: Resolved attrubutes(s) id#333L missing from departement#332,state#335,name#334. Attribute(s) with same name appear in the operation: id. Please check if the right attributes are used"

Comment: Can you try reproducing my solution using the example `df1` and `df2`; do you get the same error?

Comment: yes i am getting the same error

Comment: Ah ok. What spark version are you using?

Comment: i am using spark version 3.. but as per the error the issue not due to spark version, but rather same names on attributes ..

Comment: Any solution to this? @tjheslin

Comment: Hi Ahdi. I've tried recreating your issue but haven't been able to without a the code you are running. Could you share this? Perhaps via a [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com)?

Comment: Hi @tjheslin, i tried with your code only with the same example and seeing the same issue notified

Comment: Hi @Adhi cloud can you give further details as to your runtime set up? without which I can't reproduce your issue

Comment: Hi @tjheslin, i am running this on aws glue  version 2 and spark 3